# No version of composer-cli has been detected

Tags: node-modules, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

All,

After following the instructions in this page: [Installing the Development Environment](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/installing/development-tools.html) to install Hyperledger Composer, I encountered this error every time I use

```
sudo ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

[image]

I am sure that I have installed the correct version of composer-cli by executing these commands:

```
npm install -g composer-cli@next
```

or

```
npm install -g composer-cli@0.19.0
```

Can someone advice what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI the correct Install Doc for v0.19.0 of Composer is [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html)

It looks like you are using `sudo` for some of the commands which may well be causing the problems.  You should not need to use root or sudo.  There is additional information in the the [knowledge wiki](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#installissues) about installing.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issues. And I solved it.

1. Follow the instructions in Installing pre-requisites. 

   **Very Important**
   the link is below(I am using MacOS) : - 
   https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html
2. After completing the above step **destroy a previous setup**

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html#appendix

or

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images dev-* -q)
```

run the above command.

3. After this:-

Uninstalling the CLI tools ( 4 commands ):

```
$ npm uninstall composer-cli 
$ npm uninstall composer-rest-server 
$ npm uninstall -g generator-hyperledger-composer
$ npm uninstall -g yo
```

and installing them again

```
$ npm install -g composer-cli@0.19.0
$ npm install -g composer-rest-server
$ npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer
$ npm install -g yo
```

After that all, check

composer -v.

You will get the required version of a composer. And the continue with the steps mentioned in 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to set the path variable for npm.

Run the following command:

> npm config get prefix

This will give your npm path.

It can give something like: `/usr/local/share/npm`

Write the following command on your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file or simply run the command on your terminal:

> export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"

After that:

- open a new tab or window of the terminal
- go to your fabric directory where you have the file `createPeerAdminCard.sh`
- and run:

> ./createPeerAdminCard.sh

Now, it should run fine without the '`composer-cli not found`' error.

Comment: this worked for me this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone encountering this or related problems, note that the recommended Node version is currently 8.9.x only. See [knowledge wiki](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#installissues).

My solution was:

`nvm install 8.9.0`

`nvm use 8.9.0`

`npm install -g composer-cli`

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove sudo in prefix of the command.
It worked fine for me