# Unable to install Hyperledger-Composer on local as well as remote. Always getting stuck at ./createPeerAdminCard.sh

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to install Hyperledger-composer on my ubuntu instance on my local as well as on remote instance. But I am getting the same error everywhere which is:

"No version of composer-cli has been detected, you need to install composer-cli at v0.19 or higher"

Things which I have already tried are:

--Installing the composer-cli V0.19

--Reinstalling Node using NVM.

--Although it is not advised but I also tried to execute commands using sudo.

I am unable to figure out the exact issue here. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you run

```
composer --version
```

Does it return v0.19.0 or an error?

Did you install composer globally using the -g flag?

Did you see this post already?
[No version of composer-cli has been detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730300/no-version-of-composer-cli-has-been-detected)

Comment: It threw the following error when I tried $ composer -- version: Error: Cannot find module './api'

Comment: And yes I have installed composer-cli using -g flag. And I have seen that post already.

Comment: That sounds like your installation of composer is broken.

You could try to reinstall it with the recommended version of node:

`nvm install 8.9.4`

`nvm use 8.9.4`

`npm install -g composer-cli`

If this doesn't work, I would try to manually reinstall composer-cli as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744276/error-cannot-find-module-api-hyperledger-composer